# How do I create a loop which checks these values?

Tags: java, loops, substring, conditional-statements

If I had a numberical `idno` value, how would I find the ones `>=5000` and `< 5000`?  Would i use `idno.substring(7,11)` and then check the conditions

```
if >=5000 print Male
if <5000 print Female
```

How would I perform this?

Comment: Don't sure what u want to achive. What is input ? whats loop condition. Better to rephrase ur Q

Comment: @aberry If the number entered contains a value >=5000 at substring(7,11) print male if <5000 print Female

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check `idno % 10000` to get the value of the last four digits.**

Given that your ID number is stored as an integer:

```
int idno = ...;  // some ID number
```

You can use this comparison:

```
if (idno % 10000 >= 5000) {
    System.out.println("Male");
} else {
    System.out.println("Female");
}
```

The `if` statement is a branching operator that allows your code to branch to one block or another based on the result of the comparison.  This is different from a loop.

A loop is code that will execute repeatedly until a condition is met.  For example, if you had an array of integer ID numbers:

```
int[] idArray = {  .... , .... , .... };  // some array of IDs
```

You could loop through them like this:

```
for (int idno: idArray) {
    if (idno % 10000 >= 5000) {
        System.out.println(idno+" is Male");
    } else {
        System.out.println(idno+" is Female");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your String to integer using

```
int idno1=Integer.parseInt(idno);
```

Then simple check idno1<=5000 or idno1>5000